# What is the use of stream >> z1 when stream.peek()=='\n'

Tags: c++, class, stream, operator-overloading

```
istream& operator>>(istream& stream, list<monom>& pol)
{
    char z1,z2;
    monom m;
    stream >> noskipws;
    while(stream >> m.a >> z1 >> z2 >> m.i) {
        if (z1!=’x’ || z2!=’^’) {
            stream.setstate(ios::failbit);
            break;
        }
        pol.push_back(m);
        // This is where I do not understand why stream >> z1
        if (stream.peek()==’\n’) {
            stream >> z1;
            break;
        }
    }
    pol.sort();
    pol.remove(null);
    return stream;
}
```

I have a class `monom` and want to overload the `>>` operator for a list consisting `monom`. Looking at the code I understand everything until the point

```
if (stream.peek()==’\n’) {
    stream >> z1;
    break;
}
```

I understand that `stream.peek()` looks at the next space, and if it is empty (`== \n`) then why should it `stream >> z1`, it confuses me.

Comment: If this is not your code, why not ask the person that wrote it?

Comment: Did you read about `std::noskipws` ? I think you'll find out why the `stream >> z1` is done in there.

Comment: @NathanOliver If I had that luxury, I would

Comment: I think it's so that when data is read from the stream into the monom object, the new-lines are not placed into the object since they are instead being read into the char variable z1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code runs a loop reading `monom` items formatted as `<m.a value>x^<m.i value>` until it reaches a line break. It assumes there is no whitespace, including line breaks, between values or items.

The loop uses `peek()` to check whether each successfully read `monom` item ends with a line break or not. If a line break is present, the line break is extracted from the stream (so it does not remain in the stream for a later read to see) and the loop ends. Otherwise, the loop continues to read the next `monom` item.

The use of `noskipws` is so `operator>>` won't treat a line break as whitespace that it can skip.

Comment: That makes sense but why is `stream >> z1` necessary in the loop, surely just having `break` in there would suffice?

Comment: @user9078057 like I said, the line break is extracted from the stream before the loop ends. If the final `>> z1` were omitted, the line break would remain in the stream for a later read to extract. The line break is being used as an end-of-data marker, so it should be extracted along with the data it ends

Comment: Ok I see, but why exactly does it have to `stream >> z1` and not for example `stream >> z2 ` or `stream >> m.a`. In other words, why is the choice of `z1` necessary, it seems arbitrary to me

Comment: @user9078057 because it is arbitrary. `z1` is available at that point. The code uses `z1` and `z2` as temporary placeholders, it could have used either one in the final read of the line break. The author happened to arbitrarily pick `z1` instead of `z2`, or declaring yet another variable just for that read. It doesn't really matter in this case.